# How to test javascript code that calls window objects

Tags: javascript, testing, sinon

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
if (Notification.permission !== 'granted') {
    return Notification.permission
}
```

When I run Mocha tests on some code that uses this, the test fails:

> ReferenceError: Notification is not defined

I thought I could make this work, by doing this:

```
sinon.stub(Notification, 'permission')
```

However, I still get the same error.

How do I prevent this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first test if `Notification` exists before you run `Notification.permission`.

One way to do that, would be to replace...

```
if (Notification.permission !== 'granted') {
    return Notification.permission
}
```

... with this:

```
if (typeof Notification !== typeof undefined && Notification.permission !== 'granted') {
    return Notification.permission
}
```

Comment: This works but is there no way to do this from the test file itself? If I've got a file that has dozens of such objects do I really have to muddy up the actual working code with 100s of these checks?

I was hoping there would be a way in the test file itself to say whenever Notification.permission is called, either just ignore it or do something else. I thought mocks were meant for this but maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @Riina : You could do something like `typeof window.Notification === typeof undefined ? window.Notification = {} : false;` in your test file to create an empty `Notification object`. That should prevent the error as well, but it's a rather dirty trick and kinda defeats the purpose of testing for errors IMO...